# Unable to create Menu Item

Tags: 7, routes

I am creating a menu item using the following code.

```
$item = array(
'link_path' => 'node/custom',
'link_title' => 'Custom Title 001',
'menu_name' => 'menu-custom-menu', // Menu machine name, for example: main-menu
'weight' => 0,
'plid' => 0, // Parent menu item, 0 if menu item is on top level
'module' => 'menu',
);
menu_link_save($item);
```

I can see the entries is menu_links table, but can not see this menu item under the menu at 'admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-custom-menu'. What is wrong with my code?

Please note this path('node/custom' actually doesn't exist in Drupal System.

Comment: Where have you put this code? And have you cleared menu cache?

Comment: I am using a custom module. Using menu_cache_clear_all(); at the end of the code now. But it is not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

**Please note this path('node/custom') actually doesn't exist in Drupal System.**

Whenever we create using admin a menu it asks for a valid path otherwise it shows error of *Url doesn't exist*. So probably it enters the data in database directly but will not be listed in the admin unless it has a valid path assigned.

Please try by adding a page, e.g node/1 to the path and then try.

```
$item = array(
'link_path' => 'node/1',
'link_title' => 'Custom Title 001',
'menu_name' => 'menu-custom-menu', // Menu machine name, for example: main-menu
'weight' => 0,
'plid' => 0, // Parent menu item, 0 if menu item is on top level
'module' => 'menu',
);
menu_link_save($item);
```

and make sure **node/1** exists in the system.

Hope it will help you.